# Couldn't find Article with 'id'=1 and undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been following the JumpStartLab Blogger 2 Project and I'm stuck on what seems to be something simple.  [I'm at this point](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#i1:-form-based-workflow) Just scroll up a page where it says

```
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
```

Basically I've followed everything to a tee (I think) and after refreshing the browser after clicking the link for one of the articles I get the following error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ArticlesController#show
>
> Couldn't find Article with 'id'=1

My Articles_controller.rb looks like this

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

My index.html.erb looks like this

```
<h1>All Articles</h1>

    <ul id="articles">
    <% @articles.each do |article| %>
        <li>
            <%= link_to article.title, article_path(article), class: 'article_title', id: "article_#{article.id}" %>
        </li>
    <% end %>

</ul>

<%= link_to "Create a New Article", new_article_path, class: "new_article" %>
```

And my show.html.erb looks like this.

```
<h1><%= @article.title %></h1>
<p><%= @article.body %></p>
<%= link_to "<< Back to Articles List", articles_path %>
```

Pretty stuck here and can't figure it out.  Also I noticed another problem.  At first I forgot the

```
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
```

and I was plagued with this error which I assume will come back after I figure out the first issue.

> NoMethodError in Articles#show  show.html.erb where line #1 raised:
>
> undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass

I've looked up similar questions but they all seem to be deeper into the program than I am and were talking about private methods which I don't think I'm dealing with yet. I posted both problems because I'm not sure if they are related or not. Any advice would help me out as this is really slowing me down.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you're showing, that shouldn't be able to happen, if the link is present on your index page, then your show method should be able to find it.

Maybe your index page is out of date, or using some cache that is no longer valid. Try reloading the page, or restarting your server (and if you do this, be sure to run `spring stop` so you get a full restart), I would also run `rake tmp:clear` to clear the cache, just in case.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this now.  Question since I'm pretty new to rails servers.  Do I just Control-C out to log off and then `rails spring stop` and then run `rake tmp:clear` ?

Comment: Yes, although it should be just `spring stop` or `bin/spring stop`.

Comment: So this is odd but might be helpful.  I'm on Windows 7 btw.  `spring` or `spring stop` wasn't recognized as any command no matter what I tried.  Then I did `rake tmp:clear` and when I refreshed the browser the links to the articles were deleted.  Earlier when trying to solve this problem I did `rake db:reset` thinking that would clear the cache.  Now I'm thinking did that delete all my articles but not clear the cache causing this problem and now clearing the cache actually got rid of the articles in the browser?

Comment: `db:reset` definitely would have deleted your articles and could explain what you're seeing now.  From the rails source, `db:reset` 'Drops and recreates the database from db/schema.rb for the current environment and loads the seeds.'

Comment: @jerhinesmith Yeah that was it.  Stupid move on my part.  Like I said I'm pretty new to this.  Didn't realize that would delete my whole database.  Now I know.  The cache not being cleared is what wasn't making sense since everything was still showing up.  Thanks for the help everyone.  Everything works now.

Comment: Well, it could be worse -- at least you didn't run `db:reset` on production. :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in a udemy course, i had not added a plural form of articles while redirecting the path. I had typed

> **article_path(article)**

instead of

> **articles_path(article)**

I hope this helps someone.